# How do I get the codes of creating the sidebar from this website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

After I save the page to my machine, the sidebar is not working anymore.
I checked the links to the CSS and JS files, they are directed to the folder saved in my machine. So what is the reason?

http://www.uize.com/search-sections.html

If somehow I am not able to get the codes for the sidebar, how do I create a similar sidebar?

Comment: Did you check the files for any relative paths?

Comment: It uses Javascript and CSS, look up some tutorials for fading/animating elements.

Comment: "get the codes" sounds like something Jack Bauer only has twenty-seven minutes left to do in order to save the city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the "sharedock.js" :

http://code.google.com/p/okgo/source/browse/trunk/Eazy/js/sharedock.js?spec=svn33&r=33

Of course, you will replace the Japanese/Chinese characters with yours.